# how to upload an image by its data uri to a file input via javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, input, data-uri

I've got this line of code

```
<div class="user-post-image"> </div>
<input type="file" name="upload-image" id="upload-image" required />
```

and I have this image

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

, which I have saved to my PC, though I don't want to. When I actually upload this image, the webpage changes the div element's innerHTML with the

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64....'>
```

of my uploaded image. So I tried to change this (the div) via javascript, but it doesn't let me move on. It needs to get some kind of value on the input element, which is required, unfortunately. How do I upload my image by "giving" to the input file tag the image's data uri "value"?

Answer (score 2):

From reading your vague answer, I presume you have a function which auto converts the input file to the DIV.

So, this could possibly be a clone of [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata). From there you would send the file to a server or something by possibly an AJAX function.

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("user-post-image")[0]; //Get img data
var blob = dataURItoBlob(img); //Converts to blob using link above
var form = new FormData();
form.append("image", blob);
ajax.send(form); //The possible data sent.
```

Other then this, you may have to give more information about what "move on" means.

Comment: By move on I mean to click submit. What I have is a python script that can fetch the image, convert it to the URI, insert it in a piece of HTML code and then inject it via javascript into the `div` element. But this is irrelevant. It is only for the user to see what image he has uploaded. The form cannot be submitted if the form hasn't the required fields. So I want to inject into document.forms[1] (this is the form I want) the image URI. The data send is not a ploblem. Where did you (where do I) find that "image" string you put into form.append()? Is it the name, the id attritube?

Comment: If you just want the src cant you just do .. document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0].src ? That would give the data uri?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I don't want to use javascript in order to get something from a server. I want to manipulate a submit form in odrer to send data to a server by clicking or initiating a submit on a submit page whose input file has a "value" that I know of. I have the image URI, I want to send it as a file programmatically, like I had downloaded it and selected it with my mouse.